# Unicodeではない文字コード環境としては例えば何が挙げられますか？

Tags: 文字コード

これまで環境依存文字を使用しないよう努めてきましたが、
Windows10のメモ帳がUnicode対応していることを知り、
Unicode文字なら普通に使用しても問題ないのでは、と思ったのですが、
Unicodeではない文字コード環境を使用する例としては何が挙げられますか？

少なくともutf8で作成したWebサービスに対して、などのUnicode文字を任意のユーザーが入力しても問題ないですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unicodeではない文字コード環境を使用する例としては何が挙げられますか？

- E-mailで日本語を扱う場合、ISO-2022-JPが一般的です。
- Windowsで日本語を扱う場合、Unicodeかそれ以外であればShift-JISを使います。
- UTF-8登場前にUNIX系OSで日本語を扱う場合、EUC-JPが使われていました。

---

> Windows10のメモ帳がUnicode対応していることを知り、

参考までにWindows 2000のメモ帳であってもUTF-8（BOM有り・無し共に）を自動検出できます。

Comment: 「E-mailで日本語を扱う場合、ISO-2022-JPが一般的です。」これは今でもそうすべきですか？[RFC5322の7bit制約](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-2.1)のためだとかそれによってかなり古いメーラーや昔の携帯電話のメールがUTF-8をサポートしていなかっただとかかと思いますが、最近の(手元にある)日本語のメールをみると、iso-2022-jpかUTF-8(quoted-printableかbase64でエンコードされている)が半々くらいのようですが……

Comment: E-mail使用する場合は、注意が必要ということですね

Answer (score 2):

コンピュータは文字を `符号化文字集合` と `文字符号化方式` の組み合わせで表現しています。

Unicodeは符号化文字集合のひとつで、UTF-8はUnicodeを使った文字符号化方式のひとつです。
JIS X 0208も符号化文字集合のひとつで、Shift_JISはJISを使った文字符号化方式のひとつです。

「問題がない」かどうかは、文字をどう扱うかにかかってきます。例えば JavaScript は文字列の内部表現に UTF-16 を使っていますから、たとえJavaScriptがUTF-8で記述されていても内部表現に直接依存したコードは問題を抱えています。

```
// 文字列の長さを得るのにlengthを使うと破綻する。
console.log("".length); // => 2
```

Windowsのメモ帳は文字エンコードの欄に「Unicode」と「UTF-8」を並べて記載していますが、これは間違いです。メモ帳から「Unicode」で保存した際は「UTF-16LE」という文字符号化方式で保存されます。

---

追記:
[Windows10 1903以後は「Unicode」表示は無くなっています。](https://snow-white.cocolog-nifty.com/first/2019/05/post-7ab7a5.html)

Comment: 最後の1文は環境・版数依存ですね。Windows10 1903以後は「Unicode」表示は無くなっています。[メモ帳の文字コードが「ANSI」から「UTF-8」に【Windows 10 Ver.1903】](https://snow-white.cocolog-nifty.com/first/2019/05/post-7ab7a5.html)

Comment: まじで！知らなかった！恥ずかしい！修正しといて！！

Comment: 事情によりこれからもWindows7を使い続ける人なんかもいっぱい居るでしょうから、追記しておけばいいのでは？

Comment: 追記しました・・・事情辛い

Comment: JavaScript の(内部の)文字コードは UTF-16 なのですね。初めて知り大変驚きました